# Integrated Yii2 with linkedin return redirect_uri does not match the registered value

Tags: php, authentication, oauth-2.0, yii2, linkedin-api

I want to create login access in Yii2 which integrated with Linkedin, using yii authclient but it just return `redirect_uri does not match the registered value` in linkedin pop up page.

This is how i setting auth component in file main.php after i installed authclient:

```
    'authClientCollection' => [
        'class' => 'yii\authclient\Collection',
        'clients' => [
            'linkedin' => [
                'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\LinkedIn',
                'clientId' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
                'clientSecret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
                'scope'        => [
                  'r_basicprofile',
                  'r_emailaddress'
                ]
            ],
        ],
    ]
```

Then this i add auth action is in my AuthController:

```
  public $successUrl = '';

  ...

  public function actions() {
    return [
      'error' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
      ],
      'auth' => [
          'class' => 'yii\authclient\AuthAction',
          'successCallback' => [$this, 'successCallback'],
          'successUrl' => $this->successUrl
      ],
    ];
  }

  public function successCallback($client) {
    echo "<pre>";var_dump($client->getUserAttributes());exit;
  }
```

And the last, this is how i create button in my view file:

```
  <?=
    yii\authclient\widgets\AuthChoice::widget([
      'baseAuthUrl' => ['auth']
    ]);
  ?>
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: The error indicates that your redirect url is not registered [as documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin%2Fcontext&tabs=HTTPS#step-2-request-an-authorization-code). Did you check that?

Comment: @makadev I only got the client id and client secret key from my company, I don't know how they create app with a linkedin account. So, should I to confirm first what is the redirect uri?

Answer (score 0):

Okay finally i know the reason why this is return **redirect_uri does not match the registered value** in pop up page.

1. I did redirect the baseAuthUrl link to the wrong address, it should `'auth/linkedin'` but it doesn't end if i just change my `baseAuthUrl`, i need to change my actions too like this:

```
public function actions() {
    return [
      'error' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
      ],
      //here needs to be changed:
      'linkedin' => [
          'class' => 'yii\authclient\AuthAction',
          'successCallback' => [$this, 'successCallback'],
          'successUrl' => $this->successUrl
      ],
    ];
  }
```

then in button:

```
<?=
    yii\authclient\widgets\AuthChoice::widget([
      'baseAuthUrl' => ['auth/linkedin']
    ]);
  ?>
```

2. I did write scope parameter in the wrong way. It must be:

```
'scope' => "r_emailaddress r_liteprofile" //because linkedin using oauth v2 and there is no r_basicprofile i think, and without [ ]
```

And it works for me!